# Hello I can’t make js files in the bottom in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
function med_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('BOOT-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array(), "0.1", true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','med_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working correctly. I tested it on my development site. You need to create a main.js file in the js folder if main.js does not exist. If you write custom code for jQuery, please pass jquery in the array. for example:

```
function med_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('BOOT-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), "0.1", true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','med_scripts');
```

[Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/OM4nQDa2I4Vr)